# Union of connected space

Tags: proof-verification, connectedness

> If $\{A_\alpha, \alpha \in I\}$ is a collection of conected spaces and $\cap A_\alpha \neq \emptyset$ then $\cup A_\alpha$ is connected.

My proof: If $\cup A_\alpha$ is not connected then we can find $V,W\neq\emptyset$ such that $V\cup W = \cup A_\alpha$ and $V\cap W = \emptyset$. Suppose $\cup A_\alpha$ is not connected. Since $\cap A_\alpha \neq \emptyset$ then $\exists x\in \cap A_\alpha$. Because $V\cup W = \cup A_\alpha$ and $V\cap W = \emptyset$ $x\in V$ or $x\in W$, but if $x\in V$ then $x\notin W$ therefore $\exists \beta \in I$ such that $x\notin A_\beta$, likewise if $x\in W$. We reach a contradiction, thus $\cup A_\alpha$ is connected

Comment: the line "... therefore $\exists \beta\in I$ such that $x\not\in A_\beta$" could use more justification.

Comment: It don't think it follows as W is need be completely contained in any singlle $A_{\beta}$  Take A_1 = [0,1.2] and A_2 = [.8, 2], W=[0,8)$\cup $(1.2,2] and V = [.8,1.2].  Everything you argue is true (except the conclusion which doesn't follow).

Comment: Also you aren't using the closures can't be disjoint.  Just that the A_alpha are not disjoint.  One can always find disjoint V, W whose union is the union of As so you will never get a contradiction of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $\cup_{\alpha} A_{\alpha}$ is not connected and let $V$ and $W$ be two nonempty disjoint sets so that $V\cup W = \cup_{\alpha} A_{\alpha}$.  Let $x\in \cap_{\alpha} A_{\alpha}$.  Then $x \in V$ or $x \in W$ but not both.  Wolog let $x \in V$.

Let $y \in W$, then $y \in A_i$ for some set $A_i$.  And $x = A_i$ because $x$ is in all $A_{\alpha}$.  So $W\cap A_i$ is not empty as it contains $y$ and $V \cap A_i$ is not empty as it contains $x$.  So $A_i = (W\cap A_i) \cup(V\cap A_i)$ two disjoint non-empty sets.

Now $A_i$ is connected so either $\overline{ (W\cap A_i)}\cap  (V\cap A_i)$ is not empty or $(W\cap A_i)\cap  \overline{(V\cap A_i)}$

Let $p$ be a point in the non-empty intersection.  If $p \not \in W$ then $p \in V$ but $p$ is in $\overline{ (W\cap A_i)}$ so it is a limit point of $ (W\cap A_i)$ therefore a limit point of W and so $\overline W \cap V \ne \emptyset$.

Otherwise $p \in W$ but  $p \not \in V$ and the same argument shows $\overline{V} \cap W \ne \emptyset$.

So $\cup_{\alpha} A_{\alpha}$ can not be partitioned into two disjoint nonempty sets so that the closure of neither intersect with the other.  So the union is connected.

Answer (score 1):

Put $A = \cup_aA_a$ and assume $V$ and $W$ are two nonempty disjoint sets for which $V\cup W = A$. Take $x \in \cap_aA_a$. Surely $x \in A$, so either $x \in V$ or $x \in W$. Furthermore $x \in A_a$ for all $a$, so either $A_a \subset V$ or $A_a \subset W$, since otherwise we could write $A_a$ as a disjoint union of $V$ and $W$. In fact if $A_a$ is a subset of either $V$ or $W$ for one $a$ then every $A_a$ in the collection is a subset of the same set, since $ \cap_aA_a \neq 0$ and they are all connected. Thus $A$ is either entirely contained in $V$ or $W$. Since we have assume $A = V \cup W$ this implies one of the two must be the empty set.

Comment: "otherwise we could write Aa as a disjoint union of V and W"  What's wrong with that?  $A_{\alpha} = (A_{\alpha} \cap V)\cup((A_{\alpha}\cap W)$.  Nothing wrong with that.  So long as their closures aren't disjoint.

Comment: Since $V$ and $W$ are assumed open, as are the $A_a$, it follows that $A_a \cap V$ and $A_a \cap W$ are also open. Thus $A_a = (A_a \cap V) \cup (A_a\cap W)$ is a way of writing $A_a$ as a union of disjoint open sets, and therefore $A_a$ cannot be connected...unless I have missed something, which is quite possible :-)

Comment: So I grant that this proof does assume the $A_a$ are open, which they may not be in the topology imposed on $A$.

Comment: I was using the "the sets' closures do not intersect with the other set" rather than they are both open.  But they are equivalent.  You never actually stated that V and W were open.  And we can't assume the A are open.  We have A_i = V cap A_i cup W cap A_i but those need not be open  but their closures must intersect, and then iv V and W are open we'd get a limit point of one is an interior point of the other and that is impossible if they are disjoint.

Comment: @fleablood $V$ and $W$ must be open if $A = V \cup W$ is to be used to conclude $A$ is not connected. Otherwise simply take any partition of the interval $(a,b)$ to "prove" it is not connected! I agree on the $A_a$ however. Apparently I was thinking that each being its own space would be an open set in the union, but you are of course correct that this need not be true.